# How to generate random natural numbers in $[1, \infty)$?

Tags: random, big-numbers

Functions like `RandomInteger` draw random variates from a finite range. Can one also obtain random natural numbers in case the range extends from 1 to infinity? If so, how can we produce a list of $n$ such numbers?

Comment: "Infinite" (infinity) is not a number, so this makes no sense at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misunderstanding of the underlying mathematics, and thus it makes no sense.

Comment: This is an interesting reading you might want to look at: http://www.askamathematician.com/2010/01/q-is-it-possible-to-choose-an-item-from-an-infinite-set-of-items-such-that-each-one-has-an-equal-chance-of-being-selected/

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the question. There are a variety of common (and not so common) discrete distributions that allow one to draw a random number from the set of numbers $\{1, 2, 3, ..., \infty\}$ ... including the Geometric, Lotka, Miller, Riemann Zeta, Simon, Yule etc. I have voted for the question to be re-opened.

Comment: @wolfies well, I see a couple of issues with the question: spelling mistakes, and no mention of any requirements on the distribution. And, even though such distributions do exist, there are obvious practical obstacles to to actually producing a list of random variates from them. I fixed the spelling mistakes, but cannot do anything about the other problems. I also cast my reopen vote in the hope that you will give an answer that justifies the question, as incompletely specified as it is.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Well said! The general question is very interesting and when we ignore the practical problems, there are some nice Gedankenexperimente that lead to easy solutions.

Comment: You can always do `Floor[1/RandomReal[1, 1000]^n]`, where `n` is some fixed positive constant.

Comment: With no specified critera for the distribution, `RandomInteger[{1, 10},n]` satisfies the requirement. (`10` is just as far from infinity as any other number you might pick.).  We should not be guessing about what sort of distribution you want. voting to close as off topic.

Comment: I voted to close this question as needing more info because I feel the the OP needs to give us a clearer idea of the properties of the distributions that are wanted. Just asking for integers in $[1, \infty)$ is not good enough.

Comment: @george2079 wrote: "`RandomInteger[{1, 10},n] satisfies the requirement. (10 is just as far from infinity as any other number you might pick.).` /////// Your Uniform[1,10] distribution has a finite upper bound at 10;  this is plainly incompatible with the OP's requirement to have an open upper bound, and your example therefore does not satisfy the requirement.

Comment: any numerical implementation will have a finite bound, being the largest number you can represent.

Answer (score 17):

There are any number of discrete statistical distributions defined on the natural set of numbers (positive integers): $$\{1,2,3, ..., \infty\}$$

**Geometric**

Perhaps the best known such distribution is the Geometric with pmf:

$$P(X=x) = p (1-p)^{x-1}  \quad \text{for} \quad x = 1, 2, ...$$

with parameter $0<p<1$.

*Mathematica*'s implementation of the geometric distribution uses an alternative defn that counts from 0. I was going to say that it is easy enough to create your own definition manually via:

```
geometricdist = ProbabilityDistribution[p*(1 - p)^(x - 1), {x, 1, Infinity, 1}]
```

and then generate some pseudorandom drawings via:

```
 RandomVariate[geometricdist /. p -> .1, 100]
```

but oddly this does not seem to work, and returns the error message:

> RandomVariate::noimp: Sampling from ProbabilityDistribution[0.1 0.9^(-1+[FormalX]),{[FormalX],1,[Infinity],1}] is not implemented. >>

As a workaround, one can use $Mathematica$'s in-built `GeometricDistribution` (defined on $0, 1, 2 \dots$), and then transform it manually to the positive integers by simply adding 1 to the output. That seems to work fine, as per:

```
dataZ = RandomVariate[GeometricDistribution[.1], 1000] + 1
```

**Logarithmic**

An in-built distribution that can be used automatically is the Logarithmic distribution with pmf:

$$P(X=x) = -\frac{\lambda ^x}{x \log (1-\lambda )} \quad \text{for} \quad x = 1, 2, ...$$

which can be implemented as:

```
data = RandomVariate[LogSeriesDistribution[.8], 1000]
```

---

Alternative distributions that can be used are the:

- Beta-Geometric
- DiGamma
- Gross-Miller
- Haight Zeta
- Logarithmic
- Lotka
- Miller
- Prasad
- Riemann Zeta
- Schwarz-Tversky (Type 1)
- Simon
- Takacs
- TriGamma and
- Yule.

These are just examples from the '1 to Infinity' palette in the *mathStatica* add-on to *Mathematica*; conceptually, there are, of course, an infinite number of possible contenders.

---

The question turns out to be more interesting than I had expected, because it seems to raise the question as to whether Mma can generate pseudorandom drawings from $$\{1,2,3, ..., \infty\}$$ at least for custom distributions. The examples I have tried have so far proved unsuccessful.

It can easily be done, say here with *mathStatica*, for the same Geometric distribution:

```
        f = p (1-p)^(x - 1);             
 domain[f] = {x, 1, Infinity} && {0 < p < 1}  &&  {Discrete};
```

Then, generate 30 pseudorandom drawings with:

```
  RandomNumber[30, f /. p -> .1]
```

> {14, 7, 4, 7, 12, 12, 7, 3, 2, 9, 10, 11, 1, 6, 2, 8, 4, 2, 4, 6, 3, 4, 37, 1, 1, 1, 5, 15, 24, 8}

As another example, here is a Schwarz-Tversky (Type 1) distribution with pmf:

```
        f = 4/(x(x+1)(x+2)); 
 domain[f] = {x, 1, Infinity} && {Discrete};
```

And here again are 100 pseudorandom drawings from it:

```
RandomNumber[100, f]
```

> {1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 
>   1, 19, 1, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 7, 
>   1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 39, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
>   1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}